# Can you pass functions with arbitrary arguments but a certain type?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

To my understanding, FunctionalInterface's are contracts that ensure the argument and return type of methods you pass into another method are the correct type. For example,

```
@FunctionalInterface
private interface myFunctionType<R> {
    R execute() throws Exception;
}
```

allows you to write a function:

```
private <T> T methodCaller(final myFunctionType<T> operation) {
     return operation.execute();
}
```

where "operation" can be any function that takes 0 arguments and returns object of type T. Is there any way to write "methodCaller" so that "operation" can be any function that takes ANY arguments (but still returns an object of type T)? If not, why?

Essentially something like:

```
public T createAnimal(int age) {}
public T createLamp(String style, boolean secondHand) {}

methodCaller(() -> createAnimal(5));
methodCaller(() -> createLamp("plain", true));
```

But it would work for any function with ANY arguments, that still returns T.

Comment: [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) ? To my understanding, your myFunctionType is a supplier, not a function. Have a look at java.util.function package and you should find what you need.

Comment: What's wrong with your example? It seems to be working. Are you saying you also want to pass `methodCaller` the arguments somehow and that `methodCaller` should pass those arguments to `operation.execute(...)`? (Java doesn't have anything like variadic templates.)